# How do i add border to the table column that matches the border radius perfectly without using overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I am trying to achieve this design on the image below as a border or box-shaodow on the first td of a table.
**The most important thing is I cannot use overflow hidden because it will mess up all the dropdown inside it.**

[image]

I tried different methods using boxshadow, border but could not get to the point exactly.
Here is the snipped, this uses box-shadow but it does not exactly reflects the design on the image above.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #f1f4f8;
  height: 100vh;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1px 2px;
  border: none;
}

.table td,
.table th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: none !important;
}

.table thead th {
  border: none;
  padding: 7.5px 10px;
  background-color: #f1f4f8;
  z-index: 1;
}

.table td {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.table td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.table td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.table tbody tr:hover td:first-child {
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 0px 0px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.10.2/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-nnzkI2u2Dy6HMnzMIkh7CPd1KX445z38XIu4jG1jGw7x5tSL3VBjE44dY4ihMU1ijAQV930SPM12cCFrB18sVw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>
          Items
        </th>
        <th>
          Price
        </th>
        <th>
          Quantity
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            $200
          </td>
          <td>
            3
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Chocolates
          </td>
          <td>
            $200
          </td>
          <td>
            3
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Chocolates
          </td>
          <td>
            $200
          </td>
          <td>
            3
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I could achieve the design with this technique but the `overflow: hidden;` as in the snippet below but `overflow: hidden`; will mess up my other dropdown content inside the table column. Here is how it looks using the psuedo selector.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #f1f4f8;
  height: 100vh;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1px 2px;
  border: none;
}

.table td,
.table th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: none !important;
}

.table thead th {
  border: none;
  padding: 7.5px 10px;
  background-color: #f1f4f8;
  z-index: 1;
}

.table td {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.table td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.table td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.table tbody tr:hover td:first-child::after {
  
          width: 2px;
          height: 100%;
          background-color: #2c66ee;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          content: "";
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
        
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>
          Items
        </th>
        <th>
          Price
        </th>
        <th>
          Quantity
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            $200
          </td>
          <td>
            3
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Chocolates
          </td>
          <td>
            $200
          </td>
          <td>
            3
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Chocolates
          </td>
          <td>
            $200
          </td>
          <td>
            3
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Are there any way I can achieve this without having to use `overflow: hidden` ?

Thank you.

Comment: How about rotating in 3d?

Comment: Why not using a `linear-gradient` ? `background-img: linear-gradient(to right, blue 2px, white 2px);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use linear-gradient (also mentioned by [Amaury Hanser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7100628/amaury-hanser)) and use a css variable to handle the offset on hover

```
td:first-child {
   background: linear-gradient(
     to right, 
     #2c66ee var(--marker, 0), 
     #fff 0
  );
}
tr:hover td:first-child {
    --marker: 2px;
}
```